# How to retrieve custom post from custom database table in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin. And i have created Custom post called departments in that. Also i have stored all my departments  posts in my custom table called awr_departments table. Now i want to retrieve all departments posts in my dashboard from my custom table awr_departments, and not from inbuilt table wp_posts. I know the database query for that, but don't know the hook or filter which gets triggered for listing of custom posts in dashboard. Please guide me in this task.

*Note: I can't change core wordpress file, since i want all the functionality from my pluggin itself.*

This is my code for insertion of custom post in custom table.

```
function save_awr_details(){
global $post;
  global $wpdb;

   if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
      return;

 if ( get_post_type($post) == 'awr_department'){  

  // $post->post_status='publish';
   if(isset($post->post_title)) {
      $check=$wpdb->insert( 
                    'awr_departments', 
                    array( 
                      'title' => $_POST['post_title'],
                    )
                  );
   }
 }
}
add_action('publish_awr_department', 'save_awr_details');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to show all the results on the **wordpress dashboard**, you will have to create a **widget** to create a widget for that and then use this hook

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'yourcustom_dashboard_widget');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for retrieve data from database.

```
 $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'awr_department', //your post name
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
) );
```